# Improper Integral:$\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin x}{x+\sin x}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals

I want show that this improper integral convergence: $$\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin x}{x+\sin x}dx$$ please help me.

Comment: Different ways how to do it. Please observe that as a limit for x→0 the function is defined. So as a definite integral from, say (0,1] the integral is convergent. From (1,→), perform integration by parts. You then get behind the integral sign a (x+sinx)² in the denominator. Using Comparison theorem you can find that these integrals are convergent because x+sinx is greater than 0.5x

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For $0\lt x\le\pi$, $0\le\dfrac{\sin(x)}{x+\sin(x)}=\dfrac{\sin(x)/x}{1+\sin(x)/x}\le\dfrac12$, so
$$
0\le\int_0^{\pi}\frac{\sin(x)}{x+\sin(x)}\,\mathrm{d}x\le\frac\pi2
$$

Integrate by parts to get
$$
\begin{align}
\int_\pi^\infty\frac{\sin(x)}{x+\sin(x)}\,\mathrm{d}x
&=\left.-\frac{\cos(x)}{x+\sin(x)}\right]_\pi^\infty
-\int_\pi^\infty\frac{\cos(x)(1+\cos(x))}{(x+\sin(x))^2}\,\mathrm{d}x\\[6pt]
&=-\frac1\pi-\int_\pi^\infty\frac{\cos(x)(1+\cos(x))}{(x+\sin(x))^2}\,\mathrm{d}x
\end{align}
$$
and the last integral converges since the absolute value of the numerator of the integrand is bounded by $2$ and the denominator is greater than $(x-1)^2$.

Answer (score 4):

The integral converges near $x=0$ because the limit of the integrand is $1$ there.  And at infinity, the integrand approaches $\sin{x}/x$, which is integrable there.  To see this, Taylor expand the denominator:

$$\frac{\sin{x}}{x+\sin{x}} \approx \frac{\sin{x}}{x} - \frac{\sin^2{x}}{x^2}$$

both of which are integrable at infinity.  Further terms are still smaller.

Is there an $x \ne 0$ such that the denominator vanishes?  Let's see: $x > \sin{x}$ so that there will be no cancellation outside of $x=0$.  Thus, we have convergence.

Comment: Looking purdy on your new pic.

Comment: You are being careless at infinity, methinks.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen: I don't think so.  But just in case, I Taylor expanded to demonstrate.

Comment: Better now, yes. I am not surprised that you can do it, but consider your audience. Also, there is the example $\sum_n (-1)^n/(\sqrt{n}+(-1)^n)$, which diverges. This shows that you can't be too careful.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen: good example.

Comment: @GitGud: thanks.  My wife likes the new look, but she is really tiring of the bats.

Comment: What do you mean by "Taylor expand the denominator"...? I'm afraid I don't get it.

Comment: $$\frac{1}{x+\sin{x}} = \frac{1}{x} \frac{1}{1+(\sin{x}/x)} \approx \frac{1}{x} \left( 1 - \frac{\sin{x}}{x}\right )$$

Comment: Since the integral is not absolutely convergent, more care needs to be given than $$\frac{\sin{x}}{x+\sin{x}} \approx \frac{\sin{x}}{x} - \frac{\sin^2{x}}{x^2}$$ which does not give any idea of the error implied by $\approx$. Better might be $$\frac{\sin(x)}{x}-\frac{\sin(x)}{x+\sin(x)} =\frac{\sin^2(x)}{x^2+x\sin(x)}\le\frac1{x(x-1)}$$ Since the OP might not be familiar with why the integral of $\frac{\sin(x)}{x}$ converges, it might be good to justify that, too.

Comment: @robjohn: my argument was very crude, true, but as I said, if you keep expanding the Taylor series, you get increasing powers of sinc, which definitely converges.

Comment: @RonGordon: ah, I think what may have been causing some confusion is that the Taylor series you are using is for $$\frac{u}{1+u}=u-u^2+u^3-u^4+u^5-u^6+\dots$$which converges for $|u|\lt1$ and using $u=\sin(x)/x$ in $$\frac{\sin(x)}{x+\sin(x)}=\frac{\sin(x)/x}{1+\sin(x)/x}$$ I was not certain of that at first since you mentioned Taylor expanding the denominator.

Comment: @robjohn: yes, my apologies for not being completely clear.  I was wondering what was giving everyone fits.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is at $+\infty$, as the function tends to $1/2$ at $0$ and it is continuous on $(0,+\infty)$. Now
$$
\frac{\sin x}{x+\sin x}-\frac{\sin x}{x}=\frac{x\sin x-\sin x(x+\sin x)}{x(x+\sin x)}=-\frac{\sin^2 x}{x(x+\sin x)}\sim-\frac{\sin^2x}{x^2}
$$
at $+\infty$, so the former is integrable. And for $\frac{\sin x}{x}$, it is easy to prove convergence of the improper integral with an integration by parts on $[1,x]$.

**Note:** or as pointed out by imranfat, you can directly do integration by parts of the original integrand on $[1,x]$. It amounts essentially to the same.

Comment: For $(\sin x)/x$, the question you refer to is overkill if all you want to show is that the integral converges. It is easier to put $a_n=\int_{\pi n}^{\pi(n+1)}(\sin x)/x\,dx$ and show that $\sum a_n$ converges by the alternating series test.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen Or even better, an integration by parts. That's just the only reference I could find... I agree it does not make a great answer... I'll edit.

Answer (score 4):

We have 
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin x}{x+\sin x}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{ x}{x+ x}=\frac{1}{2}$$
hence the integral
$$\int_0^1\frac{\sin x}{x+\sin x}dx$$
is convergent

Moreover, by integration by part we have
$$\int_1^A\frac{\sin x}{x+\sin x}dx=- \left[\frac{\cos x}{x+\sin x}\right]_1^A-\int_1^A\frac{\cos x(\cos x+1)}{(x+\sin x)^2}dx$$
and with
$$|\frac{\cos x}{x+\sin x}|\leq |\frac{1}{x-1}|\to 0,\quad x\to\infty$$
and 
$$|\frac{\cos x(\cos x+1)}{(x+\sin x)^2}|\leq \frac{2}{(x-1)^2}$$
and the integral
$$\int_2^\infty \frac{1}{(x-1)^2}dx$$
is convergent so the integral
$$\int_1^\infty\frac{\sin x}{x+\sin x}dx$$
is also convergent and the desired result follows

Answer (score 0):

The integral can be compared to the convergent integral $\int_0^\infty {\sin(x)\over x}dx={\pi\over2}$.  The difference is given by $\int_0^\infty{\sin^2(x)\over {x(x+\sin(x))}}dx$, which is absolutely convergent, so the integral converges.

The convergence of $\int_0^\infty{\sin(x)\over x} dx$ is well-known, and can be established by splitting the integral up into integrals of the form $\int_{2k\pi}^{(2k+2)\pi} {\sin(x)\over x} dx$, with $k$ a positive integer.  Each of these integrals has a positive and negative component, and it is clear that $$|{\int_{(2k)\pi}^{(2k+2)\pi} {\sin(x)\over x} dx}| < {2\over{(2k)\pi}}-{2\over{(2k+1)\pi}}={1\over{k(2k+1)\pi}}\,.$$  If the upper bound is not a multiple of $2\pi$, then there will be an additional contribution of $\int_{2n\pi}^{R+2n\pi}{\sin(x)\over x}dx$, with $n$ the last positive integer for which the upper limit is smaller than $2\pi n$ and $R$ smaller than $2\pi$, but this integral is clearly less than $R\over{2n\pi}$.  The integral $\int_0^{R+2n\pi}{\sin(x)\over x}dx$ is therefore smaller than $2\pi+\sum_{k=1}^{n}{1\over{k(2k+1)\pi}}+{R\over{2n\pi}}$, with the $2\pi$ coming from the region from $x=0$ to $x=2\pi$.  Since the sum is convergent as $n$ tends to $\infty$ (limit comparison to the $p$-series with $p=2$) and the additional piece tends to zero in this limit, we can say for sure that this integral converges.  Showing that it is equal to $\pi\over2$ is a different matter, but it can be done in multiple ways (contour integration and relation to the Gamma function are the two that come to mind, but I am sure there are others).