# Evaluating $\int_0^{\infty} \text{sinc}^m(x) dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

How do I evaluate $$I_m = \displaystyle \int_0^{\infty} \text{sinc}^m(x) dx,$$ where $m \in \mathbb{Z}^+$?

For [$m=1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/5248/solving-the-integral-int-0-infty-frac-sinxx-dx-frac-pi2) and [$m=2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/13344/proof-for-an-integral-involving-sinc-function), we have the well-known result that this equals $\dfrac{\pi}2$. In general, WolframAlpha suggests that is seems to be a rational multiple of $\pi$.

\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c}
m & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7\\
\hline
I_m & \dfrac{\pi}2 & \dfrac{\pi}2 & \dfrac{3\pi}8 & \dfrac{\pi}3 & \dfrac{115\pi}{384} & \dfrac{11\pi}{40} & \dfrac{5887 \pi}{23040}\\
\end{array}

$(1)$. Can we prove that $I_m$ is a rational multiple of $\pi$ always?

$(2)$. If so, is there a nice formula, i.e., if $I_m = \dfrac{p(m)}{q(m)} \pi$, where $p(m),q(m) \in \mathbb{Z}^+$, are there nice expressions for $p(m)$ and $q(m)$?

P.S: This integral came up when I was trying my method to answer [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/378495/improper-integral-int-0-infty-frac-sin-xx-sin-xdx), by writing $\dfrac{\sin(x)}{x+\sin(x)}$ as $$\dfrac{\sin(x)}{x+\sin(x)} = \text{sinc}(x) \cdot \dfrac1{1+\text{sinc}(x)} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (-1)^k \text{sinc}^{k+1}(x)$$

Comment: Yes, $I_m$ is always a rational multiple of $\pi$, $$I_m = \frac{\pi m}{2^m} \sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor\frac{m}{2}\rfloor} \frac{(-1)^k (m-2k)^{m-1}}{k!(m-k)!}$$ You can derive the formula using contour integral.

Comment: @achillehui Thanks. Could you expand on the answer?

Comment: [This amazing paper](https://web.cs.dal.ca/~jborwein/sinc-sums.pdf) may also be of interest.

Comment: @joriki Interesting $\left(1/2 + \displaystyle \sum_n \text{sinc}^N(n) = \displaystyle \int_0^{\infty} \text{sinc}^N(x)dx \text{ valid for } N=1,2,\ldots,6 \text{ but not for }N \geq 7 \right)$ paper indeed. Thanks.

Comment: Another solution is provided by my answer [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/331404/how-to-prove-this-identity-pi-sum-limits-k-infty-infty-left-frac-sin/347951#347951).

Comment: Related OEIS sequences: http://oeis.org/A049330, http://oeis.org/A049331

Comment: See also the answers [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/307510/26872).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Notice $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin x}{x}$ is bounded at $x = 0$,

$$\begin{align}\int_0^{\infty} \left(\frac{\sin x}{x}\right)^m dx 
&= \frac12 \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \left(\frac{\sin x}{x}\right)^m dx\tag{*1}\\
&= \lim_{\epsilon\to 0} \frac12 \left(\frac{1}{2i}\right)^m \oint_{C_{\epsilon}} \left(\frac{e^{ix} - e^{-ix}}{x}\right)^m dx\tag{*2}
\end{align}$$
We can evaluate the integral $(*1)$ as a limit of a integral over a deformed
contour $C_{\epsilon}$ which has a little half-circle of radius $\epsilon$ at origin:

$$C_{\epsilon} = (-\infty,-\epsilon) \cup \left\{ \epsilon e^{i\theta} : \theta \in [\pi,2\pi] \right\} \cup ( +\epsilon, +\infty)$$

We then split the integrand in $(*2)$ in two pieces, those contains exponential factors $e^{ikx}$ for $k \ge 0$ and those for $k < 0$.

$$(*2) = \lim_{\epsilon\to 0} \frac12 \left(\frac{1}{2i}\right)^m \oint_{C_{\epsilon}}  \left( \sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor\frac{m}{2}\rfloor} + \sum_{k=\lfloor\frac{m}{2}\rfloor+1} ^{m} \right) \binom{m}{k} \frac{(-1)^k e^{i(m-2k)x}}{x^m} dx$$

To evaluate the $1^{st}$ piece, we need to complete the contour in upper half-plane. Since the completed contour contains the pole at $0$, we get:

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor\frac{m}{2}\rfloor} \text{ in }(*2)
&= \frac12 \left(\frac{1}{2i}\right)^m (2\pi i)\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor\frac{m}{2}\rfloor} \binom{m}{k} \frac{(-1)^k i^{m-1}(m-2k)^{m-1}}{(m-1)!}\\ &= \frac{\pi m}{2^m} \sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor\frac{m}{2}\rfloor} \frac{(-1)^k (m-2k)^{m-1}}{k!(m-k)!}\tag{*3}\end{align}$$

To evaluate the $2^{nd}$ piece, we need to complete the contour in lower half-plane instead. Since the completed contour no longer contains any pole, it contributes nothing and hence $I_m$ is just equal to R.H.S of $(*3)$.

**Update**

About the question whether $I_m$ is decreasing. Aside from the exception $I_1 = I_2$, it is strictly decreasing.

For $m \ge 1$, it is clear $I_{2m} > I_{2m+1}$ because the difference of corresponding integrands is non-negative and not identically zero. For the remaining cases, we have:

$$\begin{align}&I_{2m+1}-I_{2m+2}\\ 
= & \int_{0}^{\infty} \left(\frac{\sin x}{x}\right)^{2m+1}\left(1 - \frac{\sin x}{x}\right) dx\\
= & \left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \int_{2n\pi}^{(2n+1)\pi}\right) \left(\frac{\sin x}{x}\right)^{2m+1}\left[1 - \frac{\sin x}{x} - \left(\frac{x}{x+\pi}\right)^{2m+1}\left(1 + \frac{\sin x}{x + \pi}\right)\right] dx
\end{align}$$

Over the range $\cup_{n=0}^{\infty} (2n\pi,(2n+1)\pi)$, the factor $\left(\frac{\sin x}{x}\right)^{2m+1}$ is positive. The other factor $\Big[\cdots\Big]$ in above integral is bounded below by:

$$
\begin{cases}
1 - \frac{\sin x}{x} - \left(\frac{x}{x+\pi}\right)^3\left(1 + \frac{\sin x}{x + \pi}\right), & \text{ for } x \in (0,\pi)\\
1 - \frac{1}{x} - \frac{x}{x+\pi}\left(1 + \frac{1}{x}\right)
= \frac{(\pi - 2)x - \pi}{x(x+\pi)} & \text{ for } x \in \cup_{n=1}^{\infty}(2n\pi,(2n+1)\pi)
\end{cases}
$$
A simple plot will convince you both bounds are positive in corresponding range. This 
implies the integrand in above integral is positive and hence $I_{2m+1} > I_{2m+2}$.

Comment: +1. Thanks for taking time on expanding your comment to give a complete answer.

Comment: Is there an easy way to show that $I_m$ is a decreasing sequence?

Comment: why we dont take the contour in upper half-plan to compute $2^{nd}$ ?

Comment: @hmedan.mnsh the $2^nd$ piece contains exponential with -ve imaginary coefficient. If you complete the contour in upper half-plane, the contribution from the semi-circle at infinity wont' vanish.

Answer (score 11):

I hope an alternative method (to that of **achille hui**) may be of some interest. It does not use contour integration and is based on the trick employed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/373594/73025). Instead of the initial integral we consider a 2-parameter deformation 
$$ I(a,b)=\int_{0}^{\infty}x^{b-1}e^{-ax}\left(e^{ix}-e^{-ix}\right)^m dx =\sum_{k=0}^m(-1)^{m-k}{m\choose k}\int_0^{\infty}x^{b-1}e^{-(a+i(m-2k))x}dx$$
with $a>0$ and $b>0$. Obviously, it is expressed in terms of gamma functions:
\begin{align}
I(a,b)=\sum_{k=0}^m (-1)^{m-k}\bigl(a+i(m-2k)\bigr)^{-b}{m\choose k}\Gamma(b)=\\=\frac{\pi}{\Gamma(1-b)}\sum_{k=0}^m \frac{(-1)^{m-k}\bigl(a+i(m-2k)\bigr)^{-b}}{\sin\pi b}{m\choose k}
\end{align}
Now we are interested in the limit $a\rightarrow 0$, $b\rightarrow 1-m$. The prefactor becomes $\displaystyle \frac{\pi}{(m-1)!}$. To take the limit of the sum, write it as
\begin{align}\sum_{k=0}^{[m/2]}\left[\frac{(-1)^{m-k}\bigl(a+i(m-2k)\bigr)^{-b}}{\sin\pi b}+\frac{(-1)^{k}\bigl(a-i(m-2k)\bigr)^{-b}}{\sin\pi b}\right]{m\choose k}\substack{{a\rightarrow0}\\ \rightarrow}\\
\sum_{k=0}^{[m/2]}\frac{(-1)^{m-k}e^{-i\pi b/2}+(-1)^{k}e^{i\pi b/2}}{(m-2k)^b\sin\pi b}{m\choose k}=e^{-i\pi m/2}\sum_{k=0}^{[m/2]}\frac{2\cos\frac{\pi(b+m-2k)}{2}}{(m-2k)^b\sin\pi b}{m\choose k}.
\end{align}
Finally, the limit of $\displaystyle \frac{2\cos\frac{\pi(b+m-2k)}{2}}{\sin\pi b}$ as $b\rightarrow 1-m$ is computed by L'Hopital to be $(-1)^{k+m}$. Summarizing everything, we get for our integral the expression
$$ (2i)^{-m}I(0,1-m)=\frac{\pi\cdot 2^{-m}}{(m-1)!}\sum_{k=0}^{[m/2]}(-1)^k(m-2k)^{m-1}{m\choose k},$$
which coincides with the expression of **achille hui**.

Comment: Is there an easy way to show that $I_m$ is a decreasing sequence?

Answer (score 2):

Let $f(x)=\sin^m(x)$ where $m>1$. Integration by parts $m-1$ times gives the formula

$$
\int_0^{\infty}\frac{f(x)}{x^m}dx=\frac{1}{(m-1)!}\int_0^{\infty}\frac{f^{(m-1)}(x)}{x}dx.
$$

Now we have the formulae

\begin{align}
\sin^{2n}(x)&=\frac{1}{2^{2n-1}}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(-1)^{n-k}\binom{2n}{k}\cos((2n-2k)x)+\frac{1}{2^{2n}}\binom{2n}{n} \\
\sin^{2n-1}(x)&=\frac{1}{2^{2n-2}}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(-1)^{n-k-1}\binom{2n-1}{k}\sin((2n-2k-1)x).
\end{align}

Differentiate the former $2n-1$ times and the latter $2n-2$ times to obtain with the very first equation

\begin{align}
L(2n)&=\frac{\pi}{2^{2n}(2n-1)!}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(-1)^{k}\binom{2n}{k}(2n-2k)^{2n-1} \\
L(2n-1)&=\frac{\pi}{2^{2n-1}(2n-2)!}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(-1)^{k}\binom{2n-1}{k}(2n-2k-1)^{2n-2},
\end{align}

since

$$
\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\sin((2n-2k)x)}{x}dx=\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\sin(x)}{x}dx=\frac{\pi}{2}.
$$

This yields in a campact shape

$$
L(m)=\frac{\pi}{2^{m}(m-1)!}\sum_{k=0}^{\left \lfloor{\frac{m}{2}}\right \rfloor }(-1)^{k}\binom{m}{k}(m-2k)^{m-1}.
$$