# Can we calculate $\int_{0}^\infty \operatorname{sinc}^{\sqrt {13}}t \text{ d}t$

Tags: integration

> I am curious if this integral has a closed form: 
>   $$\int_0^\infty \operatorname{sinc}^{\sqrt{13}}t\,dt$$

A closed form for integer exponent is given here: [Evaluating $\int_0^{\infty} \text{sinc}^m(x) dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/378547/evaluating-int-0-infty-textsincmx-dx)

But what if the exponent is not an integer?($m\in\Bbb{Z^+}$, and $\sqrt{17}\not\in \Bbb{Z}^+$)

Comment: have you tried differentiating with respect to $c$?

Comment: I mean I read it as $\sin{c^{m}t}$. However, if there is some other function called $\sinc$, then I do not know what it does.

Comment: @user230452: It's an abbreviated form of the *sinus cardinalis* - see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinc_function.